# User Admin services WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wsdl2java, wso2-identity-server

I am using Wso2 Identity server and using its Admin services to create Users. my problem is Those user are not Able to login to system.
Below are libs, which we are using 
    
            org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework
            org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub
            5.6.14
        
        
            org.wso2.carbon
            org.wso2.carbon.utils
            4.4.10
            
                
                    xerces
                    xercesImpl
                
                
                    jaxen
                    xercesImpl
                
                
                    com.ibm.icu
                    icu4j
                
            
        
        
            org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.ws
            org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub
            5.1.3
            
                
                    commons-logging
                    commons-logging
                
            
        
        
            org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework
            org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration.stub
            5.6.14
        
        
            org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework
            org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub
            5.6.14

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2.wso2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.wso2v12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom.wso2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.11.wso2v10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.stub</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.agent.sso.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.wso2.orbit.org.opensaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1-wso2v12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.orbit.org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4.wso2v3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is my code

```
String[] roles = {"Application/myOAunth", "Internal/everyone"};
    ClaimValue sub = new ClaimValue();
    sub.setClaimURI("sub");
    sub.setValue(userSignUpRequest.getFirstName());
    ClaimValue fullName = new ClaimValue();
    fullName.setClaimURI("http://wso2.org/claims/fullname");
    fullName.setValue(userSignUpRequest.getFirstName() + " " + userSignUpRequest.getLastName());
    ClaimValue firstName = new ClaimValue();
    firstName.setClaimURI("http://wso2.org/claims/givenname");
    firstName.setValue(userSignUpRequest.getFirstName());
    ClaimValue email = new ClaimValue();
    email.setClaimURI(" http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress");
    email.setValue(userSignUpRequest.getFirstName());
    ClaimValue accountDisabled = new ClaimValue();
    accountDisabled.setClaimURI("http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountDisabled");
    accountDisabled.setValue("false");
    ClaimValue[] claims = {fullName, sub, accountDisabled, firstName};
    try {
      admin.addUser(userSignUpRequest.getEmailId(), userSignUpRequest.getPassword(), roles, claims, "default");
    } catch (AxisFault e) {
      throw new GenericException(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to log into the Identity Server management console with the created user? If so, that user need to have role with login permission.

Comment: This link[1] may help to you.
[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Role-based+Permissions

Comment: no no that user will login to OAuth application. i have assigned those roles. and permission.

Comment: In order to login to console you need Login permission. Can you verify whether the role that you assigned to role contains that permission

Comment: HI  @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne I don't want that user to be login to admin console. I want that user to be login in OAuth 2 app

Answer (score 1):

Required permission for Admin Services in **WSO2 IS** you can found here[1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Permissions+Required+to+Invoke+Admin+Services

Comment: i am able to create user but those user are not able to login in oauth application.

Comment: create new role and assign the required permission for oauth(according to above documentation). After that assign the role to the user.

Comment: I am doing the same but users were not able to login then i followed a link 
http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/07/email-username-with-identity-server/
and also made some changes in identity management conf that worked for me. :) thanks